# Generate derived matrix from index vector in matlab

Tags: matlab

Consider an index vector consisting of ones and zeros:

```
I=[0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0];
```

How can I easily generate the following matrix in matlab:

```
J=[0 2;
  1 1;
  0 1;
  1 2;
  0 3];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/diff.html):

```
I = [0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0];
d = diff(I);
ind = [1 find(d~=0)+1]; %// starting index of each new value
rep = diff([ind numel(I)+1]); %// number of repetitions of each new value
J = [ I(ind).' rep.' ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [**`strfind`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) for a slightly bigger example -

```
I =[1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0]
zero_pos = ['0' num2str(bsxfun(@eq,I,0),'%1d') '0']
ind3 = [ strfind(zero_pos,'01') ; strfind(zero_pos,'10')]
counts = diff(ind3(:))

var = zeros(numel(counts),1);
var(2:2:end)=1;
J = [var counts];
if ind3(1,1)-1>0
    J = [1 ind3(1,1)-1;J];
end
```

**Output**

```
J =
     1     2
     0     2
     1     1
     0     1
     1     2
     0     3
     1     4
     0     2
```